# Pandas dataframe: Check if data is monotonically decreasing for how long?

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, dictionary-comprehension

I am new to python and am trying to apply it to analyse stocks.

I used yahoo finance libraries and also panda data frames to get the annual dividends of stocks in their entire history.

E.g. COLB starts paying dividends from 2003 to 2019.

```
COLB start: 2003 end: 2019 diff: 16
```

```
date formatted_date   amount
0   1052141400     2003-05-05  0.04762
1   1060090200     2003-08-05  0.04762
2   1067869800     2003-11-03  0.04762
3   1076337000     2004-02-09  0.04762
4   1084195800     2004-05-10  0.07000
..         ...            ...      ...
63  1541514600     2018-11-06  0.40000
64  1549377000     2019-02-05  0.42000
65  1557235800     2019-05-07  0.42000
66  1565098200     2019-08-06  0.28000
67  1572964200     2019-11-05  0.28000
```

Then I filtered the dataframe by year and sum up the dividends of each year to put into a dictionary. Its annual dividends (div) from 2003 to 2019:

```
[{'DIV 2003': '0.14286000000000001', 'DIV 2004': '0.25762', 'DIV 2005': '0.39', 'DIV 2006': '0.5700000000000001', 'DIV 2007': '0.66', 'DIV 2008': '0.5800000000000001', 'DIV 2009': '0.07', 'DIV 2010': '0.04', 'DIV 2011': '0.27', 'DIV 2012': '0.9799999999999999', 'DIV 2013': '0.41000000000000003', 'DIV 2014': '0.94', 'DIV 2015': '1.5199999999999998', 'DIV 2016': '1.5300000000000002', 'DIV 2017': '0.88', 'DIV 2018': '1.1400000000000001', 'DIV 2019': '1.4000000000000001'}]
```

I then used panda dataframe to sort the columns by descending order:

```
df5 = df5.sort_index(ascending=False,axis=1)
```

I know how to check if the data frame is monotonically decreasing. But how do we know how long does the data frame decreases?

Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, you want to compare the values for each year?

```
dividend = [{'DIV 2003': '0.14286000000000001', 'DIV 2004': '0.25762', 'DIV 2005': '0.39', 'DIV 2006': '0.5700000000000001', 'DIV 2007': '0.66', 'DIV 2008': '0.5800000000000001', 'DIV 2009': '0.07', 'DIV 2010': '0.04', 'DIV 2011': '0.27',
             'DIV 2012': '0.9799999999999999', 'DIV 2013': '0.41000000000000003', 'DIV 2014': '0.94', 'DIV 2015': '1.5199999999999998', 'DIV 2016': '1.5300000000000002', 'DIV 2017': '0.88', 'DIV 2018': '1.1400000000000001', 'DIV 2019': '1.4000000000000001'}]
```

```
for p in dividend:
    index = list(p)
    for x in range(len(index) -1):
        if p[index[x]] < p[index[x + 1]]:
            print("The value has increased!", index[x + 1])
        else:
            print("Decreased!", index[x + 1])
```

Output:

```
The value has increased! DIV 2004
The value has increased! DIV 2005
The value has increased! DIV 2006
The value has increased! DIV 2007
Decreased! DIV 2008
Decreased! DIV 2009
Decreased! DIV 2010
The value has increased! DIV 2011
The value has increased! DIV 2012
Decreased! DIV 2013
The value has increased! DIV 2014
The value has increased! DIV 2015
The value has increased! DIV 2016
Decreased! DIV 2017
The value has increased! DIV 2018
The value has increased! DIV 2019
```

Comment: Thanks! I intend to compare the values from DIV 2019 to the start of the dividend payment to 2013. E.g. 2019's dividends are more than 2018's dividends which are more than 2017's dividends. But less than 2016's dividends. So my desired output will show the variable 3 for the number of years of increasing dividends from 2019 backwards.